# Correct gtk3 version build emacs 29.2 from source with gtk3 and xwidgets support

Tags: build, gtk3

I use linux `5.4.0-150-generic #167~18.04.1-Ubuntu` with `libgtk-3-0:amd64 3.22.30-1ubuntu4` What is the correct Gtk3 version to get xwidgets running without warnings?

1. when I run the build configuration (...see below) I get the warning:

```
configure: WARNING: Your version of Gtk+ will have problems with
       closing open displays.  This is no problem if you just use
       one display, but if you use more than one and close one of them
       Emacs may crash.
       See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
```

2. When I run Emacs, I get a popup window with warnings about potential crashes using multi display setups and possible problems closing Emacs depending on my Gtk3 version too.

Both warnings pointing to an Gtk+ version without issues but in the issue post `.../issues/221`. I cannot find a version in the info clutter of the discussion.

So which GTK3 version will work without problems?

```
 What toolkit should Emacs use?  GTK3
```

are shown.

```
./configure \
  --with-x-toolkit=gtk3\
  --with-tree-sitter\
  --with-gif\
  --with-png\
  --with-jpeg\
  --with-rsvg\
  --with-tiff\
  --with-imagemagick\
  --with-json\
  --with-xwidgets \
  --with-mailutils
```

### Configuration tests

I have tried all 4 combinations and proposed version @db48x works ..see item 4

1. `./configure`

   - configure no Gtk+ warning
   - Does Emacs support **Xwidgets? no**
2. `./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk3`

   - configure: **WARNING:** Your version of Gtk+ will have problems
   - Does Emacs support **Xwidgets? no**
3. `./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-xwidgets`

   - configure: **WARNING:** Your version of Gtk+ will have problems
   - Does Emacs support **Xwidgets? yes**
4. `./configure --with-xwidgets`

   - No warning about Gtk+
   - Does Emacs support **Xwidgets? yes**

### Summary

So the combination

1. explicit Gtk+ version `./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-xwidgets`
2. implicit Gtk+ version `./configure --with-xwidgets`

Producing an Emacs build with `GTK3 toolkit` and `xwidget` support BUT in the explicit version with a warnings at startup (popup window).

Is at least the `Gtk+ version` aspect  may be
is irrelevant in the warning context and the switch `--with-x-toolkit=gtk3` is a fossil?

I wonder what will happen, when I use the `--with-pgtk`

5. `./configure --with-pgtk --with-xwidgets`

   - No warning about Gtk+
   - Does Emacs support **Xwidgets? yes**
   - Changes the window system from X to pgtk

Ah so I guess `--with-x-toolkit=gtk3` produce the warning, which can be omitted by the implicit version.

Comment: As it stands I don't think anybody is gonna answer this question. First of all, what warnings are you talking about? Is that runtime warnings or compilation warnings? And why do you care anyway, do they disrupt your workflow in any way?

Comment: See edit above long version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is confusing, but probably mostly because you are confused, or are confusing different things with each other.

The warning you mention (“WARNING: Your version of Gtk+ will have problems…”) has nothing to do with xwidgets. All versions of Gtk have a bug where if a Gtk application (such as Emacs) is running on an X display that is on another computer, and a network outage causes it to lose it’s connection to the X server, the Gtk library inside the application will crash. You’re going to see that warning every time you compile Emacs, because the Gtk developers have refused to fix the bug. This is unreasonable of them, but in to be fair most users will never actually experience this crash because of course they don’t use X over a network. There is nothing you can do about this, so just ignore the warning.

All you have to do is configure with the `--with-xwidgets` and the resulting Emacs will support xwidgets.

Comment: There are always these confusing things .... OK have tried
all 4 combinations and indeed your proposed version works (item 4). The
`./configure setup` is indeed confusing and produces same setup
results with and without warnings (item 3 and 4) about the Gtk+
version.

Is at least the **Gtk+** version aspect may be is irrelevant in the
warning context and the `switch --with-x-toolkit=gtk3` is a fossile?


BTW: I had never an remote X server context in the question so the
confusion is brought into the context by your answer.

Comment: If you don't specify `--with-x-toolkit`, then the configure script will guess. If you have libgtk3 headers installed then it will assume that you want gtk3. If you don't, it will check for libgtk2, and so on down the list. I don't know why the warning goes away in one of the four configurations you tested; perhaps in that case you were not building with any form of gtk support at all. Just build it with the options you want and ignore the warning; it doesn’t refer to anything that will affect you.

Comment: Despite of having these ugly popup dialog when the warning was thrown and you start your Emacs. Anyway I got a solution thanks and I will close the thread.